# Datepicker only on checked checkbox

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a checkbox and a datepicker text field. It is possible to only have the datepicker functionality, after the user has checked the checkbox?
I don't want it to hidden anything at any point, so both fields should be visible at all times.

This is my elements:

```
<?php 

$disabled = "";
$checked = "";
//$checked = $res['r548'] == '1' ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "";
if ($res['r548e'] == "1") {
   $checked = "checked=\"checked\"";   
   $readonly = "readonly"; 
   $disabled = "disabled=\"disabled\"";
} else {
   $id_date = "id=\"datepicker\"";
   $readonly = "readonly"; 
}
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="r548" value="1" '. $checked . ' 
'.$disabled.'  onClick="ds.r548a.value=this.checked ? \''.date('d-m- 
Y').'\' : \'\'; ds.r548c.checked=\'\'" >';

?>

<input type="text" class="listform" style="width:60px;" name="r548a" 
value="<?php echo sqltoalmdatetom($res['r548a']);?> 

<?php echo $id_date;?>
```

This is my datepicker:

```
$( function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      regional: "da",
      constrainInput: true,
      showWeek: true
});
```

So only when the checkbox is checked, the datepicker functionality should be accessible. It that possible and if so how?

Comment: your html for the input field miss the id attribute you are then using in the javascript. add id="datepicker" if you want the js to be invoked

Comment: The PHP doesn't have anything to do with your question. You also need to show what JavaScript you tried to solve your problem.

Comment: @LelioFaieta I do have have id="datepicker", it just may not be so visible. <?php echo $id_date;?> is actually on the text input and initialize that in $id_date = "id=\"datepicker\""; This is just, because I don't want it to be a datapicker, after the user have chosen a date and saved it.

Comment: @j08691 I'm not sure what you mean. I haven't any js, to deal with this. That is what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding this javascript code:

```js
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      regional: "da",
      constrainInput: true,
      showWeek: true
});

$("#dataLocker").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $("#datepicker").prop("disabled",false);
    }else{
        $("#datepicker").prop("disabled",true);
    }
});
```

```html
<!--calling the libraries-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<input type="checkbox" id="dataLocker">
<input type="text" id="datepicker" disabled>
```

I named the ID of checkbox as "dataLocker", if you want to swap it, just swap in the HTML code and javascript too!

It is important that you add the "disabled" attribute to the "datepicker" input as well(as in the above code), so that it can already start locked.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm, not really. Now it's disabled all the time, so I can't pick a date after the checked is checked. Wonder what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Ah, stupid me, I put in the dataLocker at the wrong place, now it works.